# Export Word documents to PDF/A-2 using VBA

Tags: vba, pdf, ms-word

I'm acutally using a VBA macro in Word 2021 to Export the document to PDF/A-1:

```
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=filename, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=True
```

Ist there any way to export the document to PDF/A-2 (ISO 19005-2)?

Comment: No, there is no such parameter in Word VBA.